# nant delete subfolders exclude files

Tags: windows, batch-file, nant

need help regarding delete task in nant or command which can be used in nant build file.

here is the requirement, i have multiple files and folders in a root folder.
i need to delete only folders but not files..

Any idea how to do this.

> Blockquote

```
EX : ROOT
          -a.txt
          -b.txt
          -Folder1
          -Folder2
```

after deletion, it should be

> Blockquote

```
EX: ROOT-
        -a.txt
        -b.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the above suggustions and found it out :

Code :

```
<echo file="CleanFolders.bat">for /d %%a in ("${dir}\subdir\*") do rmdir /s /q "%%~fa</echo>
    <exec program="CleanFolders.bat"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for /d %%a in ("c:\some\root\*") do echo rmdir /s /q "%%~fa"
```

For each folder inside the indicated path, matching the indicated mask, remove the folder

Delete operations are echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command to execute the rmdir commands.

To include it in a build file, and avoid problems with quoting, it is better to create a batch file to contain the command and call this batch file. That way, the batch file will be something like

```
@echo off
    if "%~1"=="" exit /b 1
    for /d %%a in ("%~1\*") do echo rmdir /s /q "%%~fa"
```

With the path to the folder to clean passed as argument

Then, the exec task will be something like

```
<exec program="cmd.exe" commandline="/c theBatchFile.cmd" workingdir="${project.batchFiles}" output="e:\my.txt">
      <arg value="${project.rootFolder}" />
</exec>
```

The variables will need to be defined pointing to

`${project.batchFiles}` = where the batch file is located
`${project.rootFolder}` = the folder that needs to be cleaned

So, the task will call `cmd.exe` to process the batch file, passing the folder as argument to the batch.

Comment: Thanks, But I am not able to run the above code in a build file
<exec program = "cmd.exe"  commandline= 'for /d %%a in ("c:\some\root\*") do echo rmdir /s /q "%%~fa"' output="E:\my.txt".
but its not showing any errors or redirecting the output file
it's just runs and prompt doesnt return from the cmd, i could see in task manager.

Comment: @user3632330, the line i posted was inteded to be included in a batch file. I've adapted the answer to what i think you will need, but nant is not my area. Sorry for the mistakes i could be included.